delete all lines matching between two patterns in unix
delete all lines matching between two patterns in unix
eg: File contains the following
aaaaaa
aaaaa
bbbbbb
XYZ anajsksodo
argckl
wegcckl ZZZZZ
asdfg
qwett
zxcvv

I want to delete all lines where 1st character matches => XYZ and all the remaining lines until last character is => ZZZZZ
IT should return following O/P
aaaaaa
aaaaa
bbbbbb
asdfg
qwett
zxcvv

Tried below, line with XYZ is still getting printed
perl -pe 's/^(XYZ).*?ZZZZZ/$1/ms' <filename>


Please learn to use the {} tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to achieve correct code/data/output/errMsg formatting. Good luck.

It's not working because you are processing the input a line at a time, but you expect the pattern to match multiple lines.

You can do it with perl, but sed will be so much simpler and faster: sed '/^XYZ/,/ZZZZZ$/ d'

You could avoid to print the range between XYZ and ZZZZZ like so:
perl -ne 'print unless( /XYZ/ ... /ZZZZZ/ );'

If the XYZ line must actually start with XYZ, add the ^ anchor and if the ZZZZZ line must actually end with ZZZZZ and the $ anchor:
perl -ne 'print unless( /^XYZ/ ... /ZZZZZ$/ );'

Output:
aaaaaa
aaaaa
bbbbbb
asdfg
qwett
zxcvv


Just use the sed command.
sed -i '/^XYZ/,/ZZZZZ/d' filename


-i updates the file.
/^XYZ/ will match that starts with "XYZ".
/ZZZZZ$/ will match the line that ends with "ZZZZZ".
And then the d will delete all the lines in between, including the matches.

So just replace filename with your file, and it should update the file.
This will not output anything, but it will update the file. If you just want to output the result, you can take out the -i flag, like this:
sed '/^XYZ/,/ZZZZZ$/d' filename

However, if you want to display the output and store the result in another file, you can just redirect the output like this:
sed '/^XYZ/,/ZZZZZ$/d' filename > outputFile

Output
aaaaaa
aaaaa
bbbbbb
asdfg
qwett
zxcvv


Beware a range does not necessarily confirm that an end condition is met i.e. if the file does not contain a line ending in ZZZZZ, but does contain one starting XYZ,  the files will be truncated from start of the range.

Be very, very careful with the -i option to sed - it is NOT consistent across unix flavors. The form above is GNU-specific, it'll treat the script as a backup file extension on BSD-ish systems.

To make a form of s/multiline_target/some_replacement/ from command line input you need to slurp the input into a single string. By default, Perl is reading the input line by line and, therefore, a multiline substitution will fail.
This is close to your effort and works:
perl -0777 -pe 's/^XYZ.*?ZZZZZ\s+//ms' file

      ^                                 slurps the input into one string
                               ^        trailing line feeds and space

Prints:
aaaaaa
aaaaa
bbbbbb
asdfg
qwett
zxcvv

There is a difference in:
perl -0777 -pe 's/^XYZ.*?ZZZZZ\s+//ms' file

vs using a range expression such as:
perl -ne 'print unless( /XYZ/ ... /ZZZZZ/ );'

In the former, you can have the regex refer to anywhere in the line such as:
$ cat file
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
tag to start->XYZ
middle
ZZZZZ <- tag to end
ccccc
ddddd

$ perl -0777 -pe 's/XYZ.*?ZZZZZ\s+//ms' file
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
tag to start-><- tag to end
ccccc
ddddd

vs:
$ perl -ne 'print unless( /XYZ/ ... /ZZZZZ/ );' file 
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
ccccc
ddddd

You can see the s/// form allows you to replace the XYZ ... ZZZZZ and leave the remaining portion of the starting and ending lines unchanged where the range is by line logic. Neither is right or wrong -- just different tools.

I think the idiomatic word to use is "slurp" (as in File::Slurp). :)

@TLP: I do understand slurp but gulp is also used

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -i '/^XYZ/{:a;/ZZZZZ$/Md;N;ba}' file

Find a line starting XYZ and if that line or any following line ends ZZZZZ, delete it/them.
Otherwise, do nothing.
N.B. If the end of file is met and the second regexp is not, the next time the N is encountered the pattern space is printed out as normal and no further sed instructions are performed. Also the M flag allows the $ end of line zero width marker to work when multiple lines occupy the pattern space.
